# How is it chosen which dependency to inject?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Why Abp use `CustomAuthorizationHelper` in logic to check enabling feature, if Abp use your own IoC? All works fine, but i need to know why is this happening.

Using aspnetboilerplate framework. I need to implement custom `CheckFeatures()` and `CheckFeaturesAsync()` logic. I extends from `AuthorizationHelper`

```
public class CustomAuthorizationHelper : AuthorizationHelper
{
    public HrmAuthorizationHelper(
        IFeatureChecker featureChecker,
        IAuthorizationConfiguration authConfiguration) : base(featureChecker, authConfiguration)
    {
    }

    protected override void CheckFeatures(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
    {
        ///logic
    }

    protected override async Task CheckFeaturesAsync(MethodInfo methodInfo, Type type)
    {
        ///logic
    }
}
```

And `builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHelper, CustomAuthorizationHelper >();`

After that

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[RequiresFeature("featureName")]
public class MyController : AbpController
{
}
```